# Ruta script in Maven - Decrement in no. of tags

Tags: maven, uima, ruta

My Ruta script runs fine in UIMA project. But the annotation occurrences get reduced when the same scripts are included in a Maven project.

```
    LSQParen ANY+?{-PARTOF(RSQParen)} W{REGEXP("cited",true)} ANY+? RSQParen{->MARK(DZC_CITED,1,5)};
    LSQParen W{REGEXP("cited",true)} ANY+? RSQParen{-PARTOF(DZC_CITED)->MARK(DZC_CITED,1,4)};
```

In Ruta script, the no. of occurrences of DZC_CITED is 34, but in Maven it is 27.

Ex:

Input:

1.Animal Welfare Information Center [Internet]. Beltsville (MD): National
Agricultural Library (US); [updated 2001 Mar 1; cited 2001 Mar 2]. Available from:
http://www.nal.usda.gov/awic/.

2.Nursing World [Internet]. Version 3.2. Washington: American Nurses Association;
c1995-2001 [cited 2001 Mar 12]. Available from: http://www.ana.org.

3.HCMS ON LINE [Internet]. Houston (TX): Harris County Medical Society;
c2000 [updated 2001 Apr 25; cited 2001 May 1]. Available from: http://www.hcms.org.

---

Uncovered text:

```
[updated 2001 Mar 1; cited 2001 Mar 2]

[updated 2001 Apr 25; cited 2001 May 1]
```

Covered text:

```
[cited 2001 Mar 12]
```

Comment: Which version of the Ruta Workbench do you use? Which version of ruta-core do you use in the maven project? (I think there was some small bugfix chnage in the quantifier code in 2.4.0)

Comment: I tested it in a unit test in a maven project and with a run config in a Ruta project (with current trunk). In both test, three annoations are created. Ia ssume that you maven project refers to an older version of ruta-core.

Comment: btw, the pattern could be specified in a probably more efficient way. Something like (not tested): `(LSQParen #<-{CitedInd;} RSQParen){-> DZC_CITED};` ... where CitedInd is annotated by a multi tree word list... or for testing by a regex `"cited"->CitedInd;`

Comment: Thankyou ver much Peter.Yeah the problem is due to version. I used  an older version of ruta-core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was already answered in the comments.

If the same rules create different amount of annotations in a Ruta Workbench project and in a maven built porject, then most likely the version of the maven dependency to ruta-core and the version of the plugins/feature of the Ruta Workbench do not match. Different versions may result in different annotations since bugs have been fixed in later versions.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*